# Upgrading My MacBook Pro (Late 2013) Components

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, upgrade

I have a MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Late 2013) with the following specs:

2.4 GHz Intel Core i5 Processor; 
8 GB 1600 MHz DDR3 Memory; and 
Intel Iris 1536 MB Graphics.

I wanted to upgrade the Processor and Memory but having read some passages online, it seems as though I will be unable to do so.

Can anyone confirm this? Am I unable to upgrade my device?

If I can upgrade anything, what can I upgrade and how can I go about doing this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not much you can do, other than change the SSD. Apple solders essentially everything down onto the motherboard (CPU, RAM, chips...). Unless you have insanely good microsoldering skills, you can't swap the CPU or RAM.

The only think you *could* upgrade would be the SSD drive, which should be a M.2 PCIe drive, like [this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/XP941-MZHPU512HCGL-MZ-HPU512T-512GB-2280-M-2-PCI-Express-x4-SSD-/192097846687?hash=item2cb9ec859f). Even then, you'll need a Pentalobe screwdriver.

If you're interested in how irreparable your Macbook is, [here](https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/MacBook+Pro+13-Inch+Retina+Display+Late+2013+Teardown/18695) is the teardown from iFixit.